# Run AsyncTask cause Activity layout go blank

Tags: android, layout, android-asynctask

I Run a Downloader on Activity resume that it have two level inside Asynctask. first one check a version from server and on postExecute if it is needed run another asynctask and download a content. after all on post execute of second async task if every things successful the call a interface method that it is call back of my activity that close this splash activity and open next one.

I googled but my question is not same another. I do not nothing UI in any of Asynctasks.

```
new CacheUpdater(this, new CacheUpdater.CacheUpdateCallback() {
    @Override
    public void afterCacheUpdate() {

        Intent newActivity = new Intent(NoDisplay.this, MainActivity.class);
        newActivity.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent
                .FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        startActivity(newActivity);

    }
}).updateCache();
```

but why activty layout show blank eather I run this not UI task after create UI and in OnResume of Activity?
how creating or running async-task may cause in activity layout do not shown?

Comment: onPostExecute is not for background operation. You need to change the logic

Answer (score 0):

Put both of your logic in one `AsyncTask` 's `doInBackground` method .

Once both the logic are processed, then proceed with Other activity in `onPostExecute`

You can call the AsyncTask in end of your `Activity` 's `onCreate` method

```
    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {

    //Task One

    //Get result of Task 
    //Compare 
    if(comparison_is_true){

          start second Task which was initially in second AsyncTask    

    }

    return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean aBoolean) {
        super.onPostExecute(aBoolean);

        //Start your intent

    }
```

Comment: I can not do that, cause I should get the respond of first to compare and calculate if need to run a second Asynctask or not. and it is achive just in on postexecute.

Comment: For getting response of FIRST, what are you doing?  Put down all your related code ..

Comment: I wrote some wrapper on asynctask that make my code very complicated and to many classes I should copy paste here.